# Name multiple authors on a map

Tags: cartography, maps

Is it:

Authors: John Doe, Jane Doe

or

Author: John Doe, Jane Doe.

It is a small difference, but I wondered how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common method giving credit to work in the scientific world, which can also apply here. In here I am referring to the [APA6 style](http://libguides.library.usyd.edu.au/c.php?g=508212&p=3476096), but the basic are similar in other styles. I think that this principles can apply here.

When working with this method you should only write the last names and the date without the word "Authors". The names and dates are inside a parenthesis, which is the common way to  specify to the authors. In most cases you do not need to write "Authors" on the map.

For two authors write: (Doe1 and Doe2, 2018).

For three authors you  write (Doe1;Doe2 and Doe3, 2018).

Usually, when you write an article you also need to mention by which institution it was published. It is normally in the bibliography part, so maybe you should also write it done.

Comment: You say "normally" and "usually", however I've personally never seen it written like that.  Can you [edit] your answer to provide some reference to support your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Correct: Authors: JOHN DOE, JANE DOE 
(depending on the contribution of each of the co-authors, greater contribution 1 place, smaller contribution 2 place)